# Kotlin Lint Test fails, even though it works in production

Tags: java, kotlin, lint

I have an issue I'm creating, like so:

```java
public static final Issue ISSUE_PUT_BOOLEAN =
            Issue.create("NotUsingSet", "Don't use putPrimitive",
                    "Use .set() instead.",
                    Category.MESSAGES, 6, Severity.WARNING,
                    new Implementation(WrongPrefUsageDetector.class, Scope.JAVA_FILE_SCOPE));
```

When I assemble this Lint and work with it, it works correctly, like so:

[image: Lint Warning working correctly]

However, when I try to test that exact code, the test picks up no warning. This is my test:

```java
private val PUT_STUB = kotlin("""
      |package com.example.package
      |
      |import com.example.package.Prefs
      |
      |private fun putPrimitive() {
      |    Prefs(context).putBoolean("hi", true)
      |}""".trimMargin())

    @Test
    fun usingPutBoolean() {

        lint()
            .files(PUT_STUB)
            .issues(WrongPrefUsageDetector.ISSUE_PUT_BOOLEAN)
            .run()
            .expect("""1 warning or anything""".trimMargin())

    }
```

But the actual result I get is "no warnings".

Am I passing in an incorrect stub somehow? How do I diagnose the cause of the difference between the production and test scenarios? My other tests for LintChecks all pass, and they look identical, as far as I can tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the `import com.example.package.Prefs` wasn't working because my lint-check test class did not have access to this package. Therefore the `Prefs` class wasn't considered a valid class, and therefore the `putBoolean()` method wasn't considered a valid method to evaluate.

It is inadvisable to add a dependency here. Instead you should define your own class inside the Stub you create in your test class, like so:

```java
private val PREFERENCES_STUB_2 = kotlin("""
    |package com.example.package
    |
    |class Prefs {
    |
    |    fun putBoolean(key: String, value: Boolean) {}
    |    
    |    fun doWrongs() {
    |
    |        Prefs().putBoolean("abc", true)
    |    }
    |}""".trimMargin())
```

Now the putBoolean method is picked up as a valid method of the right package by the Lint Issue, which means that the warning can be registered.